# Can't add a new user to create a new organization

Tags: docusignapi

I'm writing an API integration for docusign and I wanted to create a second organization for testing, but I can't do it because when I reach the screen to add accounts to the organization, I can't see any accounts listed.

1. I visit https://admindemo.docusign.com/create-organization
2. I fill the Name and Description, and press Next
3. In the Link Accounts page, I see no accounts. How can I add some accounts to this screen?

[image: Link accounts (0)]

I'm not sure I understand the relationship between accounts and users, because I have created some users from the Admin>Users screen, but those are not displayed in the account page.

[image: Account Users]

If it isn't asking too much, could I have a short explanation of the difference between these users and what the Organization page asks for, "Accounts"? I remember when I created these "Users", I had to provide an email account, and for me that relationship between Service and Email is what I normally consider an Account.

How can I add some new Accounts to create a second Organization and test the API?

Or, since I want to create more organizations to test if DocuSign has an option to make an organization Primary, is there such an option? I tried browsing the Organization settings but I could not find this.

Can I make one organization the "Primary" organization for an account? How would this be reflected in the response of the API endpoint?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram explaining the relationship between organization, accounts, members and users. Hope this make sense.
An account can only belong to a single organization, therefore, you need another account to get another organization (but an organization can have more than one account).

[image]

Comment: Cool, this indeed helps me understand more about the system structure and the relationship between each entity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one more question then: If one account is linked only to one organization, is it safe to assume that the endpoint `https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations` which returns an array of organizations, will always return only one organization? Because the Oauth is only for one account, the array will be one-dimensional always?

Comment: well, if you look at the user in the bottom-middle in my diagram, that user belongs to two organizations. The API you call does not ask for the accountId, but the authentication uses the userId so it is possible for a user to be part of two or more organizations, but not for an account. It's a bit confusing I realize it, so hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I get it. So I think I have to get the default_account_id for the organization I want, and then use that to call the List Users API. Yes, it makes sense. Thanks a lot! :)